# Multiple boxplots from the same dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way of simplifying the code bellow; 
I have 9 different measures that I'd like to plot against quality and am trying to avoid coping and pasting the code 9 times (or even having to write a function to plot and call the function 9 times):

```
p1<- ggplot(aes(x=quality, y = alcohol), data = df) + geom_boxplot()+  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom = 'point', shape = 4)
p2<- ggplot(aes(x=quality, y = pH), data = df) + geom_boxplot()+  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom = 'point', shape = 4)
grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=1)
```

[image]

anything that can be done there?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using do.call on a list of plots generated by plyr on a melted dataframe. (I'm assuming there is a reason you do not want to use facet_grid on melted data)

```
#generate some data

data <- data.frame(id=1:500, quality=sample(3:10,replace=TRUE,size=500))

for(i in 1:9){
  data[,paste0("outcome_",i)]<-rnorm(500)
}

#melt it
melt_data <- melt(data,id.vars=c("id","quality"))
head(melt_data)


library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#generate a list of plots
plots <- dlply(melt_data,.(variable),function(chunk){
  ggplot(data=chunk, aes(x=factor(quality), y = value)) + geom_boxplot()+  
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom = 'point', shape = 4) + 
    #label y axis correctly
    labs(y=unique(chunk$variable)
    )
})


do.call(grid.arrange,c(plots,ncol=2))
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try ur code, thanks. Is not that I dont want to use face_grid; is that the way I  understand you can oly use "facet" on metadata, like lets say I had a "category" on my dataframe, than I would be able to use it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Error: could not find function "dlply" : I do have the dlply package installed, am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to add `library(plyr)'. And you're not wrong about the facets; my code also shows a way to obtain a category variable by melting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call`.

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Ozone, y = Solar.R)) + 
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point()

out <- list(p1, p1)

library(gridExtra)
do.call("grid.arrange", out)
```

Comment: thanks but I don't see how can I plot 2 different measures with this code without copying\pasting  p1's code

Comment: @Diego you can create plots by wrapping ggplot code into a for loop (or apply) and using `aes_string`.